# How to Install Completly amdgpu-pro on Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, amd-processor, amdgpu-pro

I already followed instructions on AMD website for installation of amdgpu-pro. But after finishing installation and I reboot my laptop can't run (just stuck after grub showing and login screen not show).

laptop : **Asus X550ZE-XX111D**
This is the specification of my laptop:

Processor : AMD Quad Core FX-7500 2.1 GHz (4M Cache, up to 3.3 GHz)
Graphics  : AMD Radeon™ R7 + R5 M230 2G

```
$ lspci -nn | grep '\[03' 
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kaveri [Radeon R6/R7 Graphics] [1002:1309] 
01:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Jet PRO [Radeon R5 M230] [1002:6665]
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

AMD hasn't released a driver for 18.10 yet. You've probably installed the driver for 18.04 (which is the latest), and that fails miserably (don't ask me how I know). To fix this, try switching to another virtual console (e.g. `CTRL+ALT+F2`) or boot in safe mode.

After that you have to manually remove *all* driver packages. You can search for them using: `dpkg -l | grep amdgpu`.

Then to remove them use `apt remove --purge ...`. For some packages that doesn't work and you have to remove them manually:
`dpkg -r -P ...`

Finally I had to reinstall gdm3 (or lightdm if you use that) to get it going:
`apt-get install --reinstall gdm3`.

Then reboot and it should work.

Comment: Oke i will try sir